# What is the correct way to make Validators with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I had a userSchema, first with email, username and password fields with their own validators.
Then I wanted to add more fields like bio, location gender and birthday, also with their own validators.

```
const userSchema=new Schema({
    email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true, lowercase: true, validate: emailValidators},
    username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true, lowercase: true, validate: usernameValidators},
    password: { type: String, required: true,validate: passwordValidators},
    bio: { type:String,required:false,default:null,validate:bioValidators},
    location: {type:String,required:false, default:null},
    gender: {type:String,required:false,default:null,validate:genderValidators},
    birthday: { type:Date,required:false,default:null}
});
```

Now the problem is that when i want to register, it's running every validators, so of course an error occured because in the register page i'm not even asking for the bio, location etc ..

I tried adding required:false but still not working and I didn't find any satisfying answer

**EDIT**

Here's how i create a new user

```
router.post('/register',(req,res)=>{

        if (!req.body.email) {
            res.json({success:false,message: 'You must provide an e-mail'});
        }
        else{
            if (!req.body.username) {
                res.json({success:false,message:'You must provide a username'});
            }
            else{
                if(!req.body.password){
                    res.json({success:false,message:'You must provide a password'});
                }
                else{
                    let user= new User({
                        email: req.body.email.toLowerCase(),
                        username: req.body.username.toLowerCase(),
                        password: req.body.password
                    });

                    user.save((err)=>{
                        if (err) {
                            if (err.code === 11000) {
                                res.json({success:false,message:'Username or e-mail already exists'});
                            }else{
                                if (err.errors) {
                                    if (err.errors.email) {
                                        res.json({success:false, message:err.errors.email.message});
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        if (err.errors.username) {
                                            res.json({success:false,message:err.errors.username.message});
                                        }
                                        else{
                                            if (err.errors.password) {
                                                res.json({success:false,message:err.errors.password.message});
                                            }
                                            else{
                                                res.json({ success:false,message:err});
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }else{
                                    res.json({success:false,message:'Could not save user :', err});
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else{
                            res.json({success:true,message:'Account registered'})
                        }
                    });
                }
            }

        }
    });
```

The errors i get are bioValidator and genderValidator.

In fact my question is, how do i choose which validator is going to be executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

In order to make it work simply remove the required and validators field as follows:

```js
const userSchema=new Schema({
    email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true, lowercase: true, validate: emailValidators},
    username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true, lowercase: true, validate: usernameValidators},
    password: { type: String, required: true,validate: passwordValidators},
    bio: { type:String, default:null},
    location: { type:String, default:null},
    gender: { type:String, default:null},
    birthday: { type:Date, default:null}
});
```

Comment: How do you create new user? and what is the error do you get?

Comment: Did you try to remove the `validate:bioValidators`?

Comment: Yes but if I remove it i can"t make validation on this anymore

Comment: You can do the validation pre saving using:
`userSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
    let user = this;
    if (validate(this) { // doSmoething();    } else {        // doSmoethingElse();    }
});
`